# Renamed Project, WSP name doesn't change

Tags: 2013, solution-package, rename

I have renamed my SharePoint project "SolutionName.ProjectName" in Visual Studio 2013, but the wsp is still being generated as the "SolutionName". How do I ensure the wsp takes the name of the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open The Package.Package file and change then Name attribute.

Example

```
<package xmlns:dm0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/DslTools/Core" 
dslVersion="1.0.0.0" Id="d3150724-5644-479c-99f3-fc99af5bfdc6" 
solutionId="d3150724-5644-479c-99f3-fc99af5bfdc6" resetWebServer="true" 
sharePointProductVersion="15.0"
name="NEWNAME" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/SharePointTools/PackageModel">
```

Comment: I changed the Name attribute in the file but now I get a deployment error - "Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': File not found "OldName"

Comment: Try closing VS and opening it again.

Answer (score 2):

The WSP name for a solution is defined within the Package\Package.package file of the solution as the “name” property inside the  element.

You need to open the code/project using Visual Studio, go to the Package file and then change the "name" attribute value to the desired modified name, and rebuild it.
[VS2010: Changing the SharePoint wsp file name](https://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/vs2010-changing-the-sharepoint-wsp-file-name/)